# is possible to use iframe in cdata string?

Tags: android

is possible to use iframe in android app?

Example:

```
<string name="stringName1">
    <![CDATA[<html><iframe width="100px" height="100px" name="about" src="http://www.google.com" frameborder=0></iframe></html>]]>
</string>`
```

is there any way to make it work?